# too few argument to function

Tags: php, codeigniter

controller:

```
    public function hapus ($id)
{
    $where = array ('id' => $id);
    $this->P_pejabat->hapus_data($where, 'pjbt');
    redirect ('pejabat/index');
}
```

views:

```
<td><?php echo anchor('pejabat/hapus/'.$pjb->id, '<div class="btn btn-danger btn-sm"><i class="fa fa-trash"></i></div>') ?></td>
```

and it displayed like this: Message:

> Message: Too few arguments to function Pejabat::hapus(), 0 passed in C:\xampp\htdocs\ci\system\core\CodeIgniter.php on line 532 and exactly 1 expected

Comment: function argument set null like public function hapus ($id = null) if you pass value then that value set otherwise set null value.

Comment: @JimitH. so, what should i do?

Comment: @JimitH. - I don't think that's a good solution since the method seem to need `$id` to be set.

Comment: @MagnusEriksson its default argument concept. if you sure value always getting that time no need default argument set.

Comment: @JimitH. - Yes, and if you look at the method, it requires an id to be set for it to be able to load the correct data, so instead of making a state where the method can be called without an id (where it will fail to get and present the data), they should fix the request, making sure the id is passed.

Comment: Please show us the corresponding route.

Answer (score 1):

set a [route](https://codeigniter.com/userguide3/general/routing.html) in your application\config\routes.php file:

```
$route['hapus/(:any)']='pejabat/hapus/$1';
```

then you can use in your view an [anchor](https://codeigniter.com/userguide3/helpers/url_helper.html#anchor) like:

```
anchor('hapus/'.$pjb->id,'etc..');
```

due to the route you set, the anchor now redirects to the controller `pejabat` function `hapus($id)`supplying the necessary variable `$1`, which you capture as `$id` in your function.